# Build of instance Failed to allocate the network(s

Tags: openstack, numa

I am getting below error when I am trying to create a VM with one SRIOV  interface on openstack on compute where OVS-DPDK ( NUMA enabled) is running.

ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-93dd9e62-0bc8-43c2-a641-494367bd4fc6 e2daa2dbe9414d6e937e7cd8fcd30fb8 65224a57f3ff4fd79c5754790eafb9e2 - default default] [instance: 8fd32ce0-75fc-45b1-bea0-dd3d01dff74c] Build of instance 8fd32ce0-75fc-45b1-bea0-dd3d01dff74c aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.: BuildAbortException: Build of instance 8fd32ce0-75fc-45b1-bea0-dd3d01dff74c aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.

```
  openstack server create --flavor m1.large --image vM-cloud --availability-zone nova  --nic port-id=vm_1_sriov_provider_1_port_parent  vm_1
```

**on Compute below conf**

```
on compute I can see PCI values being assigned
ip link show eno49
6: eno49: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:02:ec:80:82:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 1 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 2 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 3 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 5 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 6 MAC e2:10:d4:80:46:3f, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 7 MAC 52:57:76:b2:0b:b7, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
[root@compute admin]# ip link show eno50
7: eno50: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:02:ec:80:82:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 1 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 2 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 3 MAC aa:1f:e0:e9:63:e4, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 5 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 6 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
    vf 7 MAC f6:80:0c:f6:1a:be, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off, query_rss off
```

ovs-vsctl has below conf

```
ovs-vsctl get Open_vSwitch . other_config
{dpdk-extra="--log-level=eal,8", dpdk-hugepage-dir="/dev/hugepages", dpdk-init="true", dpdk-lcore-mask="“0x102“", dpdk-socket-mem="1024,0", dpdk_pmd_cpu_mask="0x202", n-dpdk-rxqs="2", vhost-iommu-support="true", vhost-sock-dir="/var/run/"}
[root@compute admin]#
```

nova.conf on compute has below

```
vcpu_pin_set=2,3,4,5,6,7,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,10,11,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
```

hugepages are mounted like below

```
 mount |grep huge
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
nodev on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
nodev on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages/libvirt/qemu type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
```

number of hugepages are also allocated persistenly

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/hugepages.conf
vm.nr_hugepages=16
[root@compute admin]#
```

OVS was compiled with DPDK ( NUMA enabled) lib

```
[root@compute admin]# ovs-vswitchd --version
ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.17.0
DPDK 21.11.0
```

```
 cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos_compute-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos_compute/root rd.lvm.lv=centos_compute/swap rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=16
[root@compute admin]#
```

```
numactl --hardware
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
node 0 size: 31957 MB
node 0 free: 22696 MB
node 1 cpus: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
node 1 size: 32237 MB
node 1 free: 22452 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10
```

```
[root@compute admin]# grep Huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:    614400 kB
HugePages_Total:      16
HugePages_Free:       14
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

```
[root@compute admin]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             62          17          44           0           0          44
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**On Controller**

```
 openstack flavor show m1.large
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Field                      | Value                                     |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled   | False                                     |
| OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral  | 0                                         |
| access_project_ids         | None                                      |
| disk                       | 40                                        |
| id                         | 59130eab-b5ea-4f91-a80e-1bf1a4670c20      |
| name                       | m1.large                                  |
| os-flavor-access:is_public | True                                      |
| properties                 | hw:mem_page_size='1GB', hw:numa_nodes='2' |
| ram                        | 2048                                      |
| rxtx_factor                | 1.0                                       |
| swap                       |                                           |
| vcpus                      | 6                                         |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

How to debug where is actual problem as looks like PCI from SRIOV are being assigned.

Comment: what is numa topology of compute node? that is ` --property hw:numa_nodes=1` or ` --property hw:numa_nodes=2`? based on the error description this is more of mismatch of compute (guest) instance numa mapping with physical host numa and core mapping?

Comment: Vipin,  After updating vcpu_pin_set for other numa core, it started working.
Next, I started VM creation using SRIOV port and getting below error
 VirtualInterfaceCreateException: Virtual Interface creation failed
...aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.: BuildAbortException: Build of instance 3de99c1a-7c9c-467d-b152-ce791132abbc aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.

Comment: glad to hear you were able to understand the numa error is from vcpu tagging.

Comment: I am so far not able to find any document which can help me understand all NUMA, cpu pinning, pmd, socket-mem etc settings. Any doc for OVS-DPDK which explains DPDK, NUMA related settings ?

Comment: looks liek you have already accepted the answer from @eandersson. If the answer has not solved the issue why have you accepted it?

Comment: can you work with @eandersson for the right answer, first by not accepting the answer then update the question as `I am so far not able to find any document which can help me understand all NUMA, cpu pinning, pmd, socket-mem etc settings? Any doc for OVS-DPDK which explains DPDK, NUMA related settings ?`

Comment: @VipinVarghese That is not how this site works. If the initial issue was resolved, but a new issue is encountered a new question should be created with the new issue.

Comment: @user1731045 if you have an dpdk question you should open a new question for that

Comment: @eandersson I agree toy our point that if there are new queries a separate question is to be opened @user1731045. Based on the comment shared `I am so far not able to find any document which can help me understand all NUMA, cpu pinning, pmd, socket-mem etc settings. ` it looked like @user1731045 has not been able to resolve the issue with the suggestion provided from your end. Hence I recommended to get in touch with @eandersson as you have a good amount of expertise in `nov.conf`.

Comment: Actually, to get incremental support( As I want VM to be with SRIOV and OVS-DPDK ports both) from you guys, I decided to update same query as you guys are now aware of my setup. So, in first qs I had no port, now just one SRIOV port and once this works I plan to add OVS-DPDK port also. pls accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your flavor is requesting that your VM is spread over two separate NUMA (`hw:numa_nodes` is set to `2`), but your `nova.conf` is configured to only allow VMs on one of the NUMA nodes available. You need to either change `vcpu_pin_set` to include cores from both NUMA nodes, or change your flavor to only require a single NUMA node by setting `hw:numa_nodes='1'`.

Comment: your answer solved my previous problem, thanks a lot.